# NSTimer not working with AsyncSocket library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asyncsocket

I am using the AsyncSocket library and I tried creating an NSTimer but it is not firing. When I remove the Async socket code, my timer works. I am pretty sure AsyncSockets is causing this, so how can I use NSTimers and what might be the cause of this?

Comment: More information, please. How are you creating the timer? What does it have to do with the async socket? What code did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method `addTimerToRunloop` in the AsyncSocket library that fixes this.